# Compiling a python program which uses argparse

Tags: python, windows, compilation, arguments, argparse

Me and my friends are coding a little program using argparse / socket and so on ... made to be ran on windows.
I'm actually facing a problem when i want to compile the program with argparse argument.
I would like to be able to do something like:

```
compiler C:\my\path\program.py -argparseArgument value -anotherArgument anotherValue
```

And the output of that would be a .exe containing the argument i compiled it with.
Is there any way to do that? 
Actually using pyinstaller

Comment: Assuming you're using something like `pyinstaller` to create an `exe` from a python program, freezing the argparse flags like this seems to defeat the purpose of them IMO. If you want that flexibility, I'd put the args in a `.bat` script, which you can call from the command line

Comment: The answer could very well depend on what "compiler" you're using. Please [edit] your question and specify which one it is.

Comment: I was aswell about some proposition of compiler. I made some research and find py2exe / cxfreeze but i didn't manage to complete the task i wanted. Just a novice into compiling python code

Comment: In the normal usage, your shell plus the Python interpreter put a list of the commandline strings in the `sys.argv` variable,  Your `argparse` code uses that list as input, and generates the `args` Namespace, which the rest of your code uses.    Compiling isn't going to run just the argparse part of your code, and 'compile' the rest.

Comment: Separate the core of your code into a module that can be imported without using `argparse`.  For interactive work, use a script that parsing commandline, and imports the core.  For compilation, use a different front end that doesn't need to look at the `sys.argv` (or has different defaults).

Comment: I'm kinda new to that, so i don't really know how to freeze arguments. But it seems like the good solutions. Have you any tips on how to do that with pyinstaller ? @C.Nivs